# nodeJS + Amazon-sp-api >>How to check the stock quantity for one product

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm checking the quantity of my products available in Amazon by using the report «GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA», the quantity are corrects.
When I want to check the quantity for one product, I'm using the endpoint «listingsItems»

```
await APIs[ idProductsStocksPlace ].callAPI({
  operation: 'getListingsItem',
  endpoint: 'listingsItems',
  query: {
    marketplaceIds: el.credentials.MarketplaceIds,
    includedData:  ['attributes']
  },
  path:{
    sellerId: el.credentials.MerchantIdentifier,
    sku: d.sku
  }
});
```

The report give 2 for the quantity ( it's the correct qty ) and the endpoint «listingsItems» return the following details :

> ```
> fulfillment_availability: [
>   {
>     fulfillment_channel_code: 'DEFAULT',
>     quantity: 5,
>     marketplace_id: 'AMEN7PMS3EDWL'
>   }
> ]
> ```

May be I didn't understand something.
Thanks in advance for your help.